# Set appName for PDO connections made via PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I use PDO in PHP to connect to a PostgreSQL database.
Does it allow setting the application name when making this connection?

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO ( 'pgsql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $user, $pwd );
    //$conn->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    showError ( "Error", 2 );
}
```

Comment: looks like it's just a regular query, set application_name to ...;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add to the DSN string a new element called `options` with value `--application_name=YOUR_NAME_HERE`:

```
$conn = new PDO('pgsql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname . ';options=--application_name=YOUR_NAME_HERE', $user, $pwd );
```

[image]

Credit goes for this old [user comment](http://php.adamharvey.name/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php#121791) in PHP manual.